# How to make PHPunit return nonzero exit status on warnings

Tags: php, phpunit

When invoking PHPunit on some tests which fail with warnings, I get:

```
$ phpunit -c phpunit.xml --group app
Warning - MongoCollection::insert(): expects parameter 1 to be an array or object, null given in ...
    <more output>

OK, but incomplete or skipped tests!
Tests: 17, Assertions: 81, Incomplete: 1.
```

One of the tests should fail, but it doesn't; PHPunit marks it as "incomplete".

Let's check last exit status:

```
$ echo $?
0
```

The config I am using is:

```
<phpunit
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    strict="true"
    stopOnError="true"
    stopOnFailure="true"
    stopOnIncomplete="true"
    stopOnSkipped="true"

    colors="true"
    bootstrap="bootstrap_phpunit.php"
    >
```

Any idea how to force PHPunit to emit nonzero exit status in case of "incomplete" tests?

Comment: Did you double-check that the config file is effectively being loaded? you should get a message like this: Configuration read from /your/path/phpunit.xml

Comment: I did - `colors="false"` changes output, so it is used.

Comment: Do you set a custom error handler in your code?

Comment: I did - disabling it has changed error output, but didn't change exit status.

Comment: @gontrollez: thanks! I solved it: disabling error handler didn't help, but replacing it with the one that raises an exception worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to gontrollez, I started looking into error handlers and finally found a solution:

```
set_error_handler(function ($severity, $message, $filepath, $line)
{
    throw new Exception($severity." - ".$message." - ".$filepath." - ".$line);
});
```

This code throws an exception which causes PHPunit to properly detect test as `failed` instead of `incomplete`. It should be put somewhere in `bootstrap_phpunit.php` (that is, in file, specified as `bootstrap` file).

Comment: will this work correctly though, what about tests with expected excepttions - i'm wondering if this will be called before the phpunit handling of it